# Windows 10 upgrade = CPU 100%

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have upgraded my laptop (Lenovo G500s, "i3" 3rd Gen) from windows 8.1 to windows 10 home edition (Clean upgrade). It was pretty much smooth until now but recently I received the windows 10 Anniversary update after which my CPU keeps hitting 100%. It remains calm and normal if no program is opened.

I have checked over the net for some solutions and applied many of them but to no use. It still behaving erratically and keeps on hitting 100%. Mostly when I refresh or when I open any program.

Till now what I have done to resolve it..
1. Updated all the drivers
2. disabled & removed unnecessary programs..like AV, DVD player default windows 10 apps and so on.
3. tweaked the Registry & Group Policy

Is there anything else that anyone can suggest to make it back to normal. I guess it is not performing Multi-tasking as smooth as it used to.

Please help!

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB folder) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: Sure sir will do it as soon as I get back home. Thanks.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: Hi, here is the link..Please advise now. I started a couple of apps in the end but it was already hitting 100 when started.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2An41TqBZnTTNKV2J3dkZXTVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the trace

Answer (score 0):

Most CPU usage comes from `MsMpEng.exe` which is the Antivirus of Windows (Windows Defender) when it does realtime scanning:

```
Line #, DPC/ISR, Process, Stack Tag, Stack, Count, TimeStamp (s), % Weight
8, , , ,   |    MpRtp.dll!RealtimeProtection::CFilterCommunicatorBase::CommunicatorThread, 18685, , 26,12
9, , , ,   |    MpRtp.dll!RealtimeProtection::CFilterCommunicatorBase::CommunicatorMainFunction, 18685, , 26,12
10, , , ,   |    |- MpRtp.dll!RealtimeProtection::CFileSystemWatcher::HandleRequest, 18672, , 26,10
11, , , ,   |    |    |- MpRtp.dll!RealtimeProtection::CFileSystemAgent::HandleFileScanRequest, 18609, , 26,01
12, , , ,   |    |    |    MpRtp.dll!RealtimeProtection::CFileSystemAgent::ScanFile, 18609, , 26,01
13, , , ,   |    |    |    |- MpRtp.dll!RealtimeProtection::CCMEngine::ScanFile, 18603, , 26,00
```

The next process with a high CPU usage is `rundll32.exe` which runs the `aeinv.dll` which is part of the Application Compatibility Engine. It calls the function to enum all installed software (`aeinv.dll!UpdateSoftwareInventoryW`). Windows sends the data to Microsoft to see which software users run.

```
Line #, DPC/ISR, Process, Stack Tag, Stack, Count, TimeStamp (s), % Weight
9, , , ,   aeinv.dll!UpdateSoftwareInventoryW, 2836, , 3,97
10, , , ,   aeinv.dll!CreateSoftwareInventory, 2836, , 3,97
11, , , ,   aeinv.dll!CAppInventory::PopulateItemsFromStore, 2836, , 3,97
12, , , ,   aeinv.dll!AmiProgramsEnumerate, 2836, , 3,97
13, , , ,   aeinv.dll!AmiStoreProgramsEnumerate, 2836, , 3,97
```

Next some other 3rd party tool cause some cpu usage (`Uninstaler_SkipUac.exe`, `DriverBooster.exe`, `IObitUninstaler.exe`). Remove them, they are not really needed and only damage Windows.

Comment: I'll uninstall the 3rd party tool for sure..not an issue. But what about the windows defender & Rundll32.exe. for time being I have switched off the Defender, added an exception for MsMpEng.exe in the Defenders list, edited the GPedit & Regedit (Via youtube & Tensforum)...But to no use.

Comment: I uninstalled many programs & also the drivers one by one & reinstalled the latest one manually...but nothing.

Comment: I tried to restore the Window but that says "No backup found"

Comment: I am totally exhausted now trying all these tweaks. Please tell me is there any way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have created one backup in the Pendrive if that can come to help in any way. I don't wanted to go for the fresh start as I have a huge data in my laptop (where would I keep it). Please help!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: stop/disable the Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser task in task scheduler under Microsoft -> Windows ->Application Experience. this will solve most issues.

Comment: I did as you said but still its just as it was before. I checked it for a couple of days but nothing changed.

Comment: I'll have to clean install it all over again as it is not usable in this condition. It gets really very hot within minutes.

Comment: have you disabled the Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser task in task scheduler under Microsoft -> Windows ->Application Experience? also try a different free av suite like AvastFree!

Comment: Yes..I disabled it from task scheduler as you said but nothing. Also I used to have Avast Premier before but I uninstalled in pursuit of searching the solution to this problem.